# I got this unexpected error in React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or
a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Here is the code of App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Fonts from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo-app-loading';

import Header from './components/Header';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen';
import GameOverScreen from './screens/GameOverScreen';

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Fonts.loadAsync({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState();
  const [guessRounds, setGuessRounds] = useState(0);
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!dataLoaded) {
  
  return <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    
  }

  const configureNewGameHandler = () => {
    setGuessRounds(0);
    setUserNumber(null);
  };

  const startGameHandler = selectedNumber => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };

  const gameOverHandler = numOfRounds => {
    setGuessRounds(numOfRounds);
  };

  let content = <StartGameScreen onStartGame={startGameHandler} />;

  if (userNumber && guessRounds <= 0) {
    content = (
      <GameScreen userChoice={userNumber} onGameOver={gameOverHandler} />
    );
  } else if (guessRounds > 0) {
    content = (
      <GameOverScreen
        roundsNumber={guessRounds}
        userNumber={userNumber}
        onRestart={configureNewGameHandler}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Guess a Number" />
      {content}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you exporting the components you are importing in the `App.js`?

Comment: please check all your importing and exporting components. this error occurred when you pass a "null" or "undefined" in the render method of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to "export default" in one of these components

```
import Header from './components/Header';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen';
import GameOverScreen from './screens/GameOverScreen';
```

If you are just "export"ing without "default", then use {} while importing